# Android, stackBlur two issues

Tags: android

I'm using [stackblur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur) and I have one issue and one question:

1.why `findViewById()` always returns `null`?

2.how can I make image blured by duration? I mean start by `blur = 0` and then increase it in 5 seconds to `blur = 20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** I think you are using `findViewById()` to retrieve a `View` not in the current layout(can't tell exactly as you didn't show your code so I can't figure how you implement stackblur), So, try to `inflate` the `layout` that contains the `View`, and then get the element by it's instance:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CurrentActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_contains_the_view,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_view_in_that_layout));
// So, for example if you want to get a TextView
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
```

**2-** for making the **Image Blur** increase gradientally from **0** to **20** :

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int blur = 0;
            set_image_blur(blur);
            for(int i =0; i < 5000; i++){
                blur = blur + (20*(i/5000));
                set_image_blur(blur);
            }
        }
    });
```